# Как заставить эвенты Реакта работать, если нативный эвент был запревенчен?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть Реакт компонент с `onClick`. Этот компонент помещен не в корень.
Между корнем и компонентом есть обработчик клика с `stopPropagation`. В итоге реактовский `onClick` не сработает, т.к. [реакт слушает все эвенты на рутовом элементе](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation).

Идем дальше, пытаемся отловить нативным JSом и задиспатчить его полсе того места где его превентили, получаем [следующий код](http://codepen.io/PredokMiF/pen/rLqZBE). В итоге, все нативные эвенты работают, а вот реактовские - нет. Как заставить работать реактовские эвенты?

Comment: А вариант вызывать `handleClick` внутри листенера вручную не подойдет?

Comment: Как самый экстренный случай, и то, нужно быть очень осторожным работая с DOM из под Реакта и подчищать за собой. Про кросбраузерность===off вообще молчу. Порядок выполнения эвентов тоже псу под хвост... вообще говоря, печально вешать руками нативные обработчики на каждый чих, имея мегабайтную библиотеку

Comment: Каких-то других более-менее адекватных решений я не нашел, в основном костыли, вплоть до использования react test utils для генерации евента. Для "ручного" вызова даже либы написаны типа [react-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-click-outside) и [react-outside-event](https://github.com/gajus/react-outside-event). Странно как-то... Я только не очень понимаю, почему реакт слушает document, а не например рут элемент, к которому биндится приложение?

Comment: Скорее всего это сделано для более простой обработки ситуаций, когда реакт примаунчивает компонент к другой ноде, как например это делает `react-modal`, т.о. они сильно упрощают себе жизнь, избегая кучи листнеров и дублирования событий. Что касается генерации событий тестовыми утилами - это лучше даже не пытаться использовать (в этой ситуации). Да, это есть, но на сколько я помню, только в `dev` режиме, при этом `dev` сборка в 2-3 раза медленней `prod` (недавно статья про производительность 15го реакта проскакивала).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реакт слушает события методом подобным `delegate` у jQuery, а вешается оно на `body`. Соответственно событие должно дойти до `body` и иметь `e.target` где то внутри примаунченного реактом компонента.
Как было [написано на английском стэковерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566781/handle-react-event-delegation-with-stoppropagation/38787101), мы можем сами отправить событие, но таргет не обмануть и Реактовский делегейт не сработает. В той же статье я оставил более развернутый ответ.
В сухом остатке: сейчас невозможно полечить этот баг.